# Can i save data in an android app made with python kivy creating csv file?

Tags: python, android, csv, kivy, save

I want to create an android app with kivy library in python. I would like to make an application in which you can enter alphanumeric data (such as the activities done on a given day) and then be able to view the data entered through a search bar based on the date. Can I store data by creating and editing a csv file in the phone's memory with csv libray?

I have never created an Android application and I do not know if an operation of this kind is allowed

Comment: Of course that isallowed and possible. Start programming!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.